# What's the translation of a “meme stock" in French?

Tags: traduction

A meme stock [is a](https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-a-meme-stock-5118074):

> A meme stock is a stock that has seen an increase in volume not because of the company’s performance, but rather because of hype on social media and online forums like Reddit. For this reason, these stocks often become overvalued, seeing drastic price increases in just a short amount of time.

What's the translation of a “meme stock" in French?

No good idea from gtranslate and linguee.

Comment: I could find no translation for the term. So, go ahead, Franck, and be the first to translate it. A meme stock and a viral stock are the same thing. So, the obvious translation could be: [____] fill in the blank and enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

Une [personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9299/lambie) avait [suggéré](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/125045/discussion-between-lambie-and-nemesie-t-ile) *actions/valeurs virales*. Peut-être *devenues* virales...

Comment: Oui, c'était moi et j'ai également donné la définition en anglais du terme qui est assez nouveau. meme stocks= viral stocks, ergo, in French, valeurs virales works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'un terme [informel en finance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meme_stock#English) pour un phénomène d'engouement pour l'acquisition d'actions (des [valeurs mobilières](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2071671)) moussé par/adossé aux réseaux sociaux sur internet. Un [*mème internet*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26522991) est un « élément culturel propagé de façon virale sur le Web » et sa racine renvoie à l'« imitation ». L'action cotée en bourse ne se propage pas de manière virale, c'est plutôt le fait de s'y intéresser et de s'en porter acquéreur spontanément par solidarité avec le groupe, par activisme etc. qui l'est. On peut parler d'achat d'actions impulsif induit par l'influence d'un groupe, voire quasiment en groupe...

---

Je ne sais pas si « action/valeur mobilière-mème » est utile ou clair. Je pense qu'*action* ou *titre propulsé par/sur les réseaux sociaux* est certainement clair. *Action-panacée* ? *Action de l'heure/du jour/à la page sur internet* ?

*Action-[fétiche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%A9tiche)* (ou [*mascotte*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/f%C3%A9tiche/33437) si ça ne passait pas) *d'internet*...